# How to display what version of google-cloud-bigquery is being used?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

We are receiving the error "Error accessing dataset: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'access_entries'" which may be occurring because our localhost version of App Engine is using an older version of BigQuery...but it is unclear because we have used pip to upgrade to the latest version as far as we can tell.

How do we display the version of google-cloud-bigquery in Python that we are using and verify that we are using the latest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the error messages it seems you are using the google cloud API. This being the case, see if this works for you:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
print "version: ", bigquery.__version__
```

You can also print from where the module is being imported:

```
print bigquery.__file__
```

It might help you on your debugging.